# Highcharts capture selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a high chart on my web page which is a line chart. It has a functionality to zoom and I capture the zoom event using `chart.events.selection`. That all is working fine.

But I want to continuously capture the selection event (i.e. basically click and drag event) to show a tooltip in the beginning and end of the selection to show the time user has selected. Couldn't find in high charts documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my current code to capture selection event:

```
$(obj.id).highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'areaspline',
            backgroundColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0)",
            zoomType:"x",
            events: {
                    selection: function(event){

                        if(!event.xAxis)
                            return;

                        .....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated:

Updated example in which labels following selection marker: http://jsfiddle.net/pq0wn0xx/2/

I do not think there is a drag event (not for points), but you can wrap drag pointer's method.

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Pointer.prototype, 'drag', function (p, e) {
    p.call(this, e);

    var H = Highcharts,
        chart = this.chart,
        selectionMarker = this.selectionMarker,
        bBox,
        xAxis,

        labelLeft,
        labelRight,
        labelY,
        attr,
        css,

        timerLeft,
        timerRight;

    if (selectionMarker) {
         if (!chart.customLabels) {
            chart.customLabels = [];
        }

        bBox = selectionMarker.getBBox();
        xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];
        labelLeft = chart.customLabels[0];
        labelRight = chart.customLabels[1];
        labelY = chart.plotTop + 10;

        if (!labelLeft || !labelRight) {
            attr = {
                fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                padding: 10,
                r: 5,
                zIndex: 8
            };

            css = {
                color: '#FFFFFF'
            };

            labelLeft = chart.renderer.label('', 0, 0).attr(attr).css(css).add();
            labelRight = chart.renderer.label('', 0, 0).attr(attr).css(css).add();

            chart.customLabels.push(labelLeft, labelRight);
        }

        clearTimeout(timerLeft);
        clearTimeout(timerRight);

        labelLeft.attr({
            x: bBox.x - labelLeft.getBBox().width,
            y: labelY,
            text: 'min: ' + H.numberFormat(xAxis.toValue(bBox.x), 2),
            opacity: 1
            });

        labelRight.attr({
            x: bBox.x + bBox.width,
            y: labelY,
            text: 'max: ' + H.numberFormat(xAxis.toValue(bBox.x + bBox.width), 2),
            opacity: 1
            });

        timerLeft = setTimeout(function () {
            labelLeft.fadeOut();
        }, 3000);

        timerRight = setTimeout(function () {
            labelRight.fadeOut();
        }, 3000);

    }
});
```

### Old answer:

The [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-selection/) from the official API 
can be extended to what you need.

The code and the example on jsfiddle are below:

```
function positionLabels(e, chart) {
    if (!chart.customLabels) {
        chart.customLabels = [];
    }

    var labelLeft,
        labelRight,
        attr,
        css,

        xAxis,
        xMin,
        xMax,
        yAxis,
        yMin,
        yMax,
        yMiddle,
        timerLeft,
        timerRight;

    if (!e.resetSelection) {
        labelLeft = chart.customLabels[0];
        labelRight = chart.customLabels[1];

        if (!labelLeft || !labelRight) {
            attr = {
                fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                padding: 10,
                r: 5,
                zIndex: 8
            };

            css = {
                color: '#FFFFFF'
            };

            labelLeft = chart.renderer.label('', 0, 0).attr(attr).css(css).add();
            labelRight = chart.renderer.label('', 0, 0).attr(attr).css(css).add();

            chart.customLabels.push(labelLeft, labelRight);
        }

        clearTimeout(timerLeft);
        clearTimeout(timerRight);

        xAxis = e.xAxis[0].axis;
        xMin = e.xAxis[0].min;
        xMax = e.xAxis[0].max;

        yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];
        yMin = yAxis.min;
        yMax = yAxis.max;
        yMiddle = (yMax - yMin) * 0.95;

        labelLeft.attr({
            x: xAxis.toPixels(xMin) - labelLeft.getBBox().width,
            y: yAxis.toPixels(yMiddle),
            text: 'min: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(xMin, 2),
            opacity: 1
        });

        labelRight.attr({
            x: xAxis.toPixels(xMax),
            y: yAxis.toPixels(yMiddle),
            text: 'max: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(xMax, 2),
            opacity: 1
        });

        timerLeft = setTimeout(function () {
            labelLeft.fadeOut();
        }, 2000);

        timerRight = setTimeout(function () {
            labelRight.fadeOut();
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/pq0wn0xx/

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I am looking for. I want the min and max to be visible when I am dragging and selecting the range. Any work around to do that/

Comment: You mean that you dont wan to zoom into the selected area, only show the labels with min/max? http://jsfiddle.net/pq0wn0xx/1/ If it is something different, you need to elaborate on it a little.

Comment: I want to zoom in into the area selected. But what I want is that the labels should start appearing when I starts dragging to select the area not when my selection is done. There should be two labels on max and min and the value should be continously changing when I am dragging the select the area. I hope its clear this time.. :) Thanks for you patience :)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks mate. :) BTW how did you get this done? From where did you get the docs to do all this?

Comment: There is a section called Highcharts extension in the offical website http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts and then read the Highcharts source code. If my answer solves your problem, then click a check mark next to my answer, so the topic will have an accepted answer.